# JS: String.prototype.toUnderscore()

Tags: javascript, regex

This method:

```
String.prototype.toUnderscore = function () {
    return this.replace(/(?!^.?\/)([A-Z])/g, function ($1) {
        return "_" + $1;
    }).toLowerCase();
};
```

changes `AccountUser` to `_account_user` which is obviously wrong. It should be `account_user`. So we have to exclude the first occurance. How to do it?

Googling for it is nonsense, I get only results about the library Underscore.js. My approach was:

```
(/.+(?!^.?\/)([A-Z])/g
```

but it does exactly the opposite. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is `^.?\/` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?!^.?\/|^)([A-Z])
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/5

Comment: It worked, thank you. Can you please briefly explain it?

Comment: @BarthZalewski i just modified your regex to `not include ^`...i.e the letter to be matched cannot be at the start.implemented by `|^`.`|` is for `OR` so that some other cases do not break

Comment: it could be solved simply by `(?!^.?\/?)([A-Z])` , you don't need to go further.

Comment: @avinash we don't know what original regex was designed.for...... So it's better to leave it untouched

Comment: I think both will do the same job.

Comment: Isn't the result supposed to be lower cased?

Comment: @torazaburo see the op code...after regex it is being lower cased by calling a function